# Extracorporeal shockwave therapy for finger tendon strength

Tags: research, tendons, strength-training

Background:

- [Extracorporeal shockwave therapy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3342893/) is a non-invasive treatment for a wide array of conditions, including various sorts of tendinitis, like tennis elbow or golfer's elbow.  It is billed as serving to "induce tissue repair and regeneration" (quote from preceding link).
- In some sports (notably rock climbing, but also calisthenics, parkour, and some kinds of weightlifting), tendon strength specifically in the fingers is very important.

Question:

- Is there any research on extracorporeal shockwave treatment as a way to strengthen tendons in the fingers?

Comment: Welcome Yly. This is a medical site. What you seem to have here is a link to a medical paper with 129 referenced papers, all medical, then you are asking a non-medical question. This is problematic as we require questions to be medical in nature, not about medicalised body-building of a healthy body. That being said, I'll defer to more experienced members  to decide about this.

Comment: I'm prone to agree with @LittlePickle. since you're asking about its use as strength conditioning for otherwise healthy tendons. There are many articles about it being used to treat tendinopathies, but using it purely for strength conditioning isn't a medical question. I think the question would be more appropriate on Fitness.SE.